# django ajax form submission for multiple values in for loop

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, django

I have a django template like this :

```
{% for comment in service.comments.all %}
{{comment.comment}} -- commented by {{comment.user}}<br/>
{% for reply in comment.comment_replies.all %}

{{reply.comment_reply}} -- replied by {{reply.user}}<br/>

{% endfor %}
<form id="comment-replyform" action="/comment/reply/{{comment.id}}/" method="post">{% csrf_token %}

  {{ comment_reply_form.as_p }}

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Reply">
</form>

{% empty %}
No comments 
{% endfor %}
```

Here I want to reply to comment using ajax.. so that page wont refresh..
I have written javascript code for this ..

```
$('#comment-replyform').on('submit', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
           url: $(this).attr('href'),
           success: function(data) {
                    alert("Success");

            }
            });

    })
```

Here I see a success alert for only first comment reply form.. When I send from another comment reply field( because there might be many comment reply form for many comments).. It does not call ajax and refresh the page...

How can I post this form with comment message ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML ids must be unique. You can't have multiple forms all with the same id. Use a class instead.

```
<form class="comment-replyform" action="/comment/reply/{{comment.id}}/" method="post">

$('.comment-replyform').on(...)
```

Note that you don't seem to be doing anything with the form contents though, so the submission still won't actually work.